# How can I add <li> to <ul> for chat application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function addMessageToBody(chat)
{
    var htmlSTR = "";
    htmlSTR = "<p>another paragaraph</p>";

    //htmlSTR += "<li class="left"><span class="username">Doruk</span>";
    //alert(htmlSTR);
    //$("#message-lists").html(main);
}
```

```html
<body background="Orange.png">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://91.234.35.26/iwiki-admin/v1.0.0/admin/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-white border-top-green">
                <div class="panel-body chat">
                    <div class="row chat-wrapper">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="compose-area">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 550px;">
                                    <div class="chat-list-wrapper" style="overflow-y: auto; width: auto; height: 550px;">
                                        <ul class="chat-list" id="olasimesajlar">
                                            <li class="text-center">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default">Olası Mesajlar</a> </li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 2 </li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 3 </li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 4</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 5</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 6</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 7</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 8</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 9</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 10</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 11</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 12</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 13</li>
                                            <li>Liste Numara 14</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div><div class="slimScrollBar" style="width: 7px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 0.4; display: none; border-radius: 7px; z-index: 99; right: 1px; height: 478.639px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div><div class="slimScrollRail" style="width: 7px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: none; border-radius: 7px; opacity: 0.2; z-index: 90; right: 1px; background: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></div></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8">


                            <div>

                                <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 452px;">
                                    <div class="message-list-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 452px;">
                                        <ul class="message-list" id="message-lists">
                                            <li class="text-center">
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default" >Load More Messages</a>
                                               <!-- <button id="loadmoremessages" onclick="loadMoreMessages()">Load More Messages</button> -->
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="left">
                                                <span class="username">Ozan</span>
                                                <small class="timestamp">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>3 mins ago
                                                </small>
                                                <span class="avatar available tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip " data-placement="right" data-original-title="Yanique Robinson">
                                                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/597340997157298176/2XUqrs3R.jpg" alt="avatar" class="img-circle">
                                            </span>
                                                <div class="body">
                                                    <div class="message well well-sm" id="mesajleft">
                                                        ..........
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                    <div class="message well well-sm">
                                                        <p><a href="#" class="white">....</a> .........</p>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="right" id="rightside">
                                                <span class="username">Rasim Ozan</span>
                                                <small class="timestamp">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>3 secs ago
                                                </small>
                                                <span class="avatar tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip " data-placement="left" data-original-title="Kevin Mckoy">
                                                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/597340997157298176/2XUqrs3R.jpg" alt="avatar" class="img-circle">
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="body">
                                                    <div id="mesajright" class="message well well-sm">
                                                        Czczczczczczczczccz
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div><div class="slimScrollBar" style="width: 7px; position: absolute; top: 265px; opacity: 0.4; display: none; border-radius: 7px; z-index: 99; right: 1px; height: 187.092px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div><div class="slimScrollRail" style="width: 7px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: none; border-radius: 7px; opacity: 0.2; z-index: 90; right: 1px; background: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></div></div>

                                <div class="compose-box">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 mg-btm-10">
                                            <textarea name="messageinput" id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4" id="deneme">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <button id="sendbutton" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-green btn-sm pull-right">
                                                <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Send
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have this HTML and JavaScript code. This is a kind of chat application. So every time when button pressed I want to add messages to screen. My css is complex so I want to do that as passing HTML code into it via JavaScript. **LİKE**

```html
 <li class="left">
                                                <span class="username">Ozan</span>
                                                <small class="timestamp">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>3 mins ago
                                                </small>
                                                <span class="avatar available tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip " data-placement="right" data-original-title="Yanique Robinson">
                                                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/597340997157298176/2XUqrs3R.jpg" alt="avatar" class="img-circle">
                                            </span>
                                                <div class="body">
                                                    <div class="message well well-sm" id="mesajleft">
                                                        ..........
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                    <div class="message well well-sm">
                                                        <p><a href="#" class="white">....</a> .........</p>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
```

adding/append this HTML code via JavaScript dynamically to **ul** section.

How can I do that ?

Comment: `element.insertAdjacentHTML`

Comment: Can you give a small example please. I am new in JavaScript. But I couldnt find useful information for this kind of thing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML --- Please try to research more on your own. You'll get better that way.

Comment: I also want to ask, is my technique logical ? Do you suggest something else ?

Comment: read the docs on jquery.append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery, so you can simply do it like

```
$("#message-lists").append(htmlSTR);
```

But if the html of your message rows (li-s) are big and difficult you should rather do it with JSON responses and build the message rows on client side with js (based on the received data). Also I would recommend using some javascript template engine like Mustache or Handlebars.

Comment: How can set message to left side or right side. I want to show server message in rightside. which is <li class="right " id="rightside">

Comment: @DorukSu This is the very basics of html and css. First, remove the id="rightside", it is bad usage of the id attribute. In your css file you need to add `.right { text-align: right; }` and `.left { text-align: left; }` I highly recommend you to learn css from this site: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `innerHTML`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('message-lists');

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<p>another paragaraph</p><li 
class='left'><span class='username'>Doruk</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an event listener for your button.
2. In your event handler function, append your htmlSTR. This gets run every time your button gets clicked.

As you seem to be using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    var htmlSTR = "<li><p>another paragaraph</p></li>";
    var $ul = $('#olasimesajlar');
    var $button = $('#id_of_your_button');

    $button.click(buttonClickHandler);

    function buttonClickHandler(){
        $ul.append(htmlSTR);
    }
});
```

Comment: My htmlSTR like last picture, very long. Is this logical that pushing HTML code with every message ? .

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you adding a lot of elements every time the button is clicked?

Comment: @DorukSu if that's what your app requires, then yes.

Comment: No. All I want to sending messages which it is a chat application to screen. So every message is <ul> element and its also have different timestamp etc. When button clicked it sends message and shows in screen(obviously).When user write messages it shows message in left corner which is <li class="left"> when server send response it shows in right which is <li class="right" id="rightside"> . Answer for IIpo Oksanen.

Comment: If you want to get the text from an element, check out jQuery's `input.val()`. If you want to send it to a server, check out `jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.post()`.